# Assist in debugging vba module

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if someone could assist me with debugging the following module, I believe my only issue lies in the last (if) statement in order for cells to be filled in with a color. The general module creates a cell range of randomized numbers that should be filled in with the colour red if an input of a certain value is entered in the input box. Thanks!

```html
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim user As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim random_number As Integer
Dim itm As Integer


For Each cell In Range("A1:J10")

random_number = Int(100 * Rnd) + 1
cell.Value = random_number

Next

Dim mycount As Integer
 
Dim myarray(1 To 10, 1 To 10)

For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To 10
         myarray(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value
Next
Next

user = CInt(InputBox("enter a number betweeen 1 and 100"))
If user < 1 Or user > 100 Then
    msgbox ("Error, wrong value entered")
    Exit Sub
End If


For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To 10
        If myarray(i, j) > user Then
           Range(Cells(i, j)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)


    itm = itm + 1
        End If

Next
Next


      
msgbox itm

     

End Sub
```

Comment: Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Comment: Ah thank you. I guess the range doesn't need to be defined afterwords.

Answer (score 1):

See @Gary'sStudent comment to debug your code.

If you are willing to learn using the amazing power of arrays, ranges and the Excel/VBA duo, which is a **must** if you are going to work with this technology in the long term, try rewriting your code this way:

```
Sub test()
  Dim user As Long
  With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J10")
    ' Generate random numbers using formula then fix values
    .Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1, 100)"
    .value = .value

    ' Enter a number
    user = Application.InputBox("enter a number betweeen 1 and 100", Type:=1) ' <-- Enter a number
    If user < 1 Or user > 100 Then
      MsgBox ("Error, wrong value entered")
      Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Higlight the value using conditional formatting.
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, user).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

   ' Count of items that match the value
    MsgBox Application.CountIf(.Cells, ">" & user)
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ha! I had been thinking along these exact same lines.

Comment: (... but the user may get confused between .Name and .CodeName if not previously exposed to the use of .CodeName)

Comment: Should it be `Application.CountIf(.Cells, ">" & user)` ?

Comment: @Jeeped yes, I changed it to make it easier at this stage. Main thing was to put some dot `.` before the range ;)

Comment: @jeeped yes and also `xlGreater`.

Comment: Ah yes, but this new sub doesn't seem to work? What would be a better way of completing my original sub in order for it to work?

Comment: @JaySmith Trust me, **this** is the better way. How doesn't it work? It is fully tested. Only verify that you have a worksheet named `"Sheet1"`, or use an existing sheet name.

Comment: Which part of this however better utilizes the array?